# Python Pandas AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'columns'

Tags: python, pandas

This code :

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('house', sep="\t", header=None)
data.columns = ['label', 'msg']
data['msg_length'] = data['msg'].apply(lambda x: len(x))
data['msg'].hist(column =data['msg_length'], by=data['label'], bins=50)
```

Gives me this error:

AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'columns'
`

I have tried different things with pd.DataFrame and pd.Series, without luck.
What do i wrong?

Result of pd.read_csv:
[image]

Expected output:
[image]

Error code:

[image]

Comment: if `data` is a `pd.Series`, it indeed has no columns. Can you check its type - what is the result of the `pd.read_csv`?

Comment: Do you need `data.hist(column ='msg_length', by='label', bins=50)` ?

Comment: does not work @jezrael

Comment: @ItamarMushkin i have added a picture to the question

Comment: What is expected output ?

Comment: @jezrael i have added it to the question

Comment: hmmm, can you explain `data.hist(column ='msg_length', by='label', bins=50)`  why not working? some error?

Comment: Wait, which line raises the error? Please post the error traceback. As code, not as image - please do not post code or errors as images. To learn more, please visit https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: ok thanks for the adivce @Itamar Mushkin but i dont manage to add the error code without the error that i have too much code and not enough text ...

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.hist`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.hist.html) with columns in strings instead `Series` like `data['msg_length']`:

```
data.hist(column ='msg_length', by='label', bins=50)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data.hist(column ='msg_length', by='label')
```

did the job